# Express Js Routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

api route:

```
/Token?l=Spanish&n=NameofTheServer&m0=Email&m1=&m2=&m3=&m4=&m5=&m6=&m7=&m8=&m9=&m10=&m11=&m12=&m13=&m14=&m15=&m16=&m17=&m18=&m19&v=VersionOfTheServer&hw=NumberOfTheHardware
```

This is my route, i want to write it on the express route using regex

```
router.post('/:token?/:Language/:NameOfTheServer/:Email...)
```

So i can retrieve the information on a console log so i can get 
the Token + the Language + the Name of the Server + the Version + the Number of the hardware.

Comment: just defining `app.route('/token')` will work because all other are query params. which you can access via req.query.params in callback function.

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary no need of params also, only `req.query` will return all query params.

Comment: If it's post-call why don't you send data in request body?

Comment: Want to know how can i get the l= as the language , the mo= as the Email ?
the hw as the number of the hardware?etc..

Comment: @RahulSharma yes it's a post call with param, i want to get the param that i posted and console.log them.

Comment: instead of sending data in params send it in the body.

Comment: @RahulSharma yeh but if i want to access only email from query parameter i will do ```req.query.email``` .it's in that sense :D

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary that correct, But it's post-call so better to pass in the request body.

Comment: @RahulSharma agreed so added both approach in my answer :)

Comment: Not like this,
When i send the request /Token?l=language&n=Name&m0=email&m1=&m2=&m3=&m4=&m5=&m6=&m7=&m8=&m9=&m10=&m11=&m12=&m13=&m14=&m15=&m16=&m17=&m18=&m19&v=4.1.2&hw=6

I want when to acess to the l, the n , the m0, the v, and the hw.

Answer (score 0):

when you will hit this api:`/token?l=spenish&n=NameofTheServer&m0=Email`

```
route.post('/token, function(req,res, next){
 //console.log(req.query) 
 // here it will be available  some thing like this
 //req.query = {l: 'spenish',n:'NameofTheServer', m0:'Email'}
});
```

or if you pass your data in body you can access it in `req.body`.

Comment: Not like this,
When i send the request /Token?l=language&n=Name&m0=email&m1=&m2=&m3=&m4=&m5=&m6=&m7=&m8=&m9=&m10=&m11=&m12=&m13=&m14=&m15=&m16=&m17=&m18=&m19&v=4.1.2&hw=6

I want when to acess to the l, the n , the m0, the v, and the hw.

Comment: @Taieb yes you will get it like this only. please read answer carefully. you will get all these properties in req.query object .

Comment: I want to do something like this 

 let param=[];
 var token=req.params.token;
 var lang=req.params.lang;
 var nameb=req.params.nameb;
 var setting=req.params.setting;
 var mail=req.params.mail;
 var version = req.params.version;
 var hw = req.params.hw;
 
  if (token.length==18 & setting==m) {
  param.push({token:token},{language: lang},{namb:nameb},{setting:setting},{mail:mail},{version:version});
  res.send(param);
  console.log(param);
  }else{
   console.log('Param is incorrect')
  }

Comment: @Taieb you will not get anything in ```req.params``` all the query params you pass will be available in form of object in ```req.query```.